# Which would be proper between "have seen" and "saw" and why?

Tags: tense

A man in a buffet restaurant suddenly recalls something irritating and frustrating, so the man gets anxious because of it and he starts to move around in a circle mumbling by himself.

After several seconds of doing that, the man pulls himself together and realizes he is acting weird and stops moving and asks himself this question.

> "Oh, my god. I am acting weird. I wonder if a lot of people **have seen me act weird**."
>
> "Oh, my god. I am acting weird. I wonder if a lot of people **have seen me acting weird**."
>
> "Oh, my god. I am acting weird. I wonder if a lot of people **saw me act weird**."
>
> "Oh, my god. I am acting weird. I wonder if a lot of people **saw me acting weird**."

Which would be nicer here and why is it? Any explanations would be appreciated. :)

Comment: I can't point to a proper rule, but in my experience, "saw" usually refers to some recent or particular event: *I saw that performer last week,* and "have seen" usually refers to one or more earlier events: *I have seen that performer three times.* - new comment, as I had no edit option. Thanks.

Comment: @Davo: **saw** refers to an event in the past. I saw your car keys **this morning**. I **saw** him for the first time **ten years ago**, acting weird in a restaurant.

Comment: @MarkHubbard Thank you for the advice. But before doing that, would I be able to ask you to explain the reason for it? I don't appreciate what is wrong with "nicer" there.

Comment: Smart, I take it back and will delete my comment. Nothing is *wrong* with "nicer." This is one of my favorite questions *ever*!

Comment: Without applying any other polish to the sentence, the fourth choice makes the most sense. Most people elide the last two words though, avoiding the implied repetition of `acting weird`.

Comment: I'm curious why you chose a **buffet** restaurant to locate your example.  Is there a reason why people might "freak out" more often in that kind of restaurant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> have seen me act weird.
>
> have seen me acting weird.

In this context, the use of the present perfect ("have seen") indicates a *life experience*.  In other words, the man is asking if anyone has had the experience of seeing his odd behavior *at anytime in the past*.  Since the context is related to the single, most recent incident, this doesn't make sense, and you should not use the present perfect.

> saw me act weird.
>
> saw me acting weird.

"Saw me act weird" indicates that they saw the entire action, and so in context it *sounds* like this is something he does *all the time*, either now or in the past.  It's not *wrong* but also not quite right for your intended meaning.

Meanwhile, "saw me *acting* weird" (the present progressive) indicates an action in progress, and sounds more like he's referring to the most recent incident.

So, to answer your question:

> I wonder if a lot of people saw me acting weird.

works best in this context.  In a different context, any of the others could be correct.

Comment: Andrew, thank you so much for the excellent answer. This explanation is so helpful to me. It took me some time to fully study your explanation. I appreciate it very much. I think you got exactly __what I was wondering about__. This is another story but, Here, among __what I was wondering about__ and __what I wondered about__, which is more appropriate here? :)

Comment: @SmartHumanism none really.  We say "what was I (just) thinking about?" when you forget what you were thinking.  A related expression when you can't understand why you did something in the past, is "what was I thinking?!"  It would be easy to get these confused, but you can usually tell from inflection and context.

Comment: What you mean by "none" is that there is no difference there between "what I wondering about" and "what I wondered about"? So could I use either interchangeably in the comment there? :)

Comment: @SmartHumanism sorry I wasn't clear.  I meant that we (or at least I) don't use the verb "wonder" in that context.

Comment: I am very sorry for not just accepting your reply. But I am a bit not sure in the first comment that I delivered you my exact intention. What I was trying to say in the comment was that you answered to the very points that I really wanted to know about. So I used the verb "wonder" in that way.

Comment: @SmartHumanism  It might be worth asking a separate question, the difference between "I wonder" and "I think" and also "I was wondering" and "I wondered" and "I was thinking" and "I thought", at least in a particular context.

Answer (score 3):

> "Oh, my god. I am acting weird. Would there be a lot of people who saw
>   me acting weird?"

That is grammatically correct but still sounds weird to me. I am in North America, so it could be a regional thing.

I'd say, **"Oh, my god, I am acting weird(ly). I wonder if a lot of people  saw me acting weird(ly)?"**

Adding the **ly** is grammatical but in common usage -- most people do drop the ly.

On Edit: The phrase **nicer** is confusing. I think you mean, **better**. "Nicer" means kinder/friendlier. "Better" means more accurate/in common usage/a good choice of wording.

The use of **acting** means you must use the word weird**ly.** This is my opinion. I doubt that it matters grammatically, but to my ear, it simply sounds better.

I think you need one of our grammar gurus to explain it.

Comment: Depends on the buffet.

Comment: Thank you for the answering. But what I really want to know about is missing. But I altered the question as you pointed out, and your answer is very helpful. Thank you. If it is okay, I would like to ask you to answer the question as altered.

Answer (score 1):

Acting weird is a gerund, gerunds can be subjects of a sentence:
Acting weird is a problem teenagers have. Playing tennis is fun. Same thing.

Act weird cannot be the subject of a sentence. i.e. Act weird is x. That is not grammatical in English.

Difference between acting weird versus act weird as an object:

People saw me [once] act weird [a single act].
People saw me acting weird. [saw the behavior constituted by acting weird as it unfolded]

People have seen me act weird [in the past, unspecified, people saw me perform an act of weirdness]

People have seen me acting weird [in the past, unspecified, people saw me performING weirdly as it unfolded].

Oh, my god. I **am acting** weird. I wonder if a lot of people **saw me** act weird. **Those sentences are grammatical individually but do not work as a pair**.

**was acting weird**, saw me acting weird or act weird, for example, would work as a pair.

Comment: Thank you for the good point. But I would like the answer focused more on what I am asking, which are written in bold in the question. And in the middle of "I am acting weird." and "I wonder if a lot of people saw me act weird." could the man just stopped the weird movement.

Comment: I answered your questions: These two sentences: Oh, my god. I am acting weird. I wonder if a lot of people saw me acting weird. do not work together logically. Think about this: I'm playing tennis. I wonder if a lot of people saw me playing tennis. I really do not know how else to explain it!  /I am acting weird/ can be followed by MANY THINGS but not: saw me act weird unless it is further clarified: I wonder if many people saw me act weird last week, too. Then, YES, for example.

Comment: I have got your point, thank you, Andrew. But I would like to know the difference in meaning between "People saw me act weird." and "People saw me acting weird." and also the difference between "People have seen me act weird." and "People have seen me acting weird." regardless of the context in my original question. :)

Comment: There is no need to repeat the same thing over and over. Also, I am NOT Andrew.

Comment: My mistake, Lambie. I am sorry for mistyping your name. I was a little bit tired trying hard to understand your explanations. I am not reading your answers roughly but thoroughly. But you actually didn't mention the difference in the meaning.  What you said is that the tense in the sentences did not go along with each other. I understood that. Please don't misunderstand me. I appreciate your answer and comments.

Comment: Actually, I did. acting weird (general, unspecified, a subject [not grammatical, a subject like subject of a book]) versus act weird (perform an act of weirdness) subject as in: Acting weird is fun. That is the subject of the sentence and the subject as idea. The tense that DO NOT GO are: am acting weird FOLLOWED BY saw me act weird. They are fine grammatically but do not MAKE SENSE. ***I'm playing*** tennis. I wonder if a lot of people ***saw me*** play tennis. Same thing, It doesn't work.

Comment: I am very sorry that I made you repeatedly explain that to me. Thank you so much. I have totally understood your explaining about tense.

Comment: @Smart Humanism I am so very glad. :)